# cURL failing to submit POST data

Tags: php, forms, curl

I'm trying to submit a simple form with cURL. After obtaining the login cookie and submitting the data I want, I get a random response and form fails to submit. Here is what it looks like when browser submits a form:

```
formPost:cur_product_form_new_86286
curCheckbox:Y
C2cProductsListing[business_hr_from]:10:00:00
C2cProductsListing[business_hr_to]:09:30:00
C2cProductsListing[online_hr]:35
C2cProductsListing[offline_hr]:16
C2cProductsListing[non_business_hr]:17
C2cProductsListing[actual_quantity]:25000
C2cProductsListing[minimum_quantity]:25000
C2cProductsListing[products_base_currency]:USD
C2cProductsListing[products_price]:88
delivery[1]:1
C2cProductsListing[c2c_products_listing_id]:86286
```

Here is what it looks like when I submit the form:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.g2g.com/sell/manageListingInfo'); // open a protected page
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.g2g.com/sell/manageListing?game=2522&product_type=19248');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
$data = array(
    'formPost' => 'cur_product_form_new_86286',
    'curCheckbox' => 'Y',
    'C2cProductsListing' => array(
        'business_hr_from' => '09:00:00',
        'business_hr_to' => '08:30:00',
        'online_hr' => '35',
        'offline_hr' => '16',
        'non_business_hr' => '17',
        'actual_quantity' => '25000',
        'minimum_quantity' => '25000',
        'products_base_currency' => 'USD',
        'products_price' => '25',
        'c2c_products_listing_id' => '86286'
    ),
    'delivery' => array(
        '1' => '1'
    )
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.g2g.com/sell/manageListing?game=2522&product_type=19248');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));

curl_close($ch);
```

And here is the completely random response I get:

```
Array ( [url] => http://www.g2g.com/sell/manageListingInfo [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => 0 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) )
```

The array I just posted is result of `print_r(curl_getinfo($ch))`. How do I end up here? I emulated the browser request fully (aside from it being cURL and not the actual browser) using all the data necessary, yet the form doesn't seem to be submitted?

Comment: It could be something simple like a session variable that is set on the server when you open the form to avoid submits bypassing the form.

Comment: @jeroen I'm overly confused over the results I get. From what I know, I've completely cloned the form data. Before I do all this, I have cURL login, fetch the cookie, and try to submit it. Same process on browser works just fine

Comment: Fetch the cookie or fetch the form? There are all kinds of tricks people can use to avoid automated form submissions, like setting a session variable, timing the time it takes to request the form and submit the form (too fast, not valid), etc. If it is setup like that, it will be a lot of trial and error to get it to submit successfully.

Comment: @jeroen just fetch the cookies, so that I'm freshly logged in.

Comment: Don't they have an API you can use instead?

Comment: @jeroen I wish >.< I have to use curl for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling [`curl_exec`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) to actually execute the query. Call `curl_getinfo` afterwards. If you want the data returned use the return value of `curl_exec` instead of  `curl_getinfo`. For example:

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $data;
```

Comment: I just did. This changes the result I get to something even weirder such as http://pastebin.com/KugtC3CE (too long for comment)

Comment: That is nothing “weird”, that is just some info about the response the remote server gave you. And that it says `url: http://www.g2g.com/account/login` means that the site has redirected you back to its login form, because the data you passed it did not prove that you were successfully logged in already.

Comment: getinfo shows information about the transfer as opposed to the data it returns. [http_code] => 200 is showing that the http request was successful.

Comment: @CBroe it does use the cookie I snatched a minute ago?

Comment: Well, maybe that cookie is not enough – as jeroen already said in another comment, there is more that can distinguish a user using a normal browser from a bot. (I’d start by looking at _all_ the request headers your browser sends, and try implementing those that you have not send with your cURL request yet.)

Comment: @AsksAnyway `echo $data` will return a page of the site that says 'welcome back (userid) click here to continue' and I have to hit a link to go back to the site. It's some sort of protection from something, bit tricky to explain. Same happens if you have a protected page open in your browser and you re-launch the browser. Something like that.

Comment: _“It's some sort of protection from something”_ – well, most likely it’s protection _against what you are trying to do here_ :-)

Comment: Nah, they don't mind me doing this, already checked. I'm really trying to employ trial&error here but it's hard with insufficient knowledge. Thought someone might recognise a common mistake I made or something. Guess it's back to curling ^^

Comment: CURL was failing to post because of the lack of a curl_exec() call. I suggest asking a new question about cookies or simulating a real browser session instead of stringing along this one.

Comment: @AsksAnyway yeah that's the plan, just got loads and loads to read up before I ask a stupid or vague question =)